# Find Voltage using Complex Impedance

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, voltage, complex-numbers

[image]

I am trying to calculate the Voltage at the top right segment ($V_{out}$ in the diagram).

Importantly, I'm trying to calculate this voltage *using complex impedance.*

I know in the complex impedance model, you take resistance $R$ and convert them into $Z$ forms. For example, for the $10n$ conductor, you would use $Z_c = \frac{1}{ic*\omega}$

Then, I'd treat this as a circuit with resistors in series and try to approach it that way. My attempts at this approach aren't working well. I think I need to apply frequencies to get $V_{in}$.

Does anyone have any thoughts on obtaining $V_{out}$?

Comment: What do you mean by the capacitor being labeled 10n. What is "n"?

Comment: hint: think voltage divider $V_{out}=\frac{ Z_c}{Z_c+R} V_{in}$

Comment: 10n is a unit measurement for circuit types. It's the same as 0.01 $\mu$F

Comment: This is classic "phasor analysis".  This is in the realm of "Electrical Engineering" as much or maybe even moreso than "Physics" - we use this all the time.  Except we use "j" instead of "i" because "i" means "current"  ;)    And you are correct that "Vout" is a function of FREQUENCY.   The circuit drawn is a low-pass filter... Vout will be higher for lower frequencies.

Answer (score 0):

In phasor notation you simply have a voltage divider

$$\overrightarrow{V_{out}} = \frac{1/i\omega C}{R+1/i\omega C} \overrightarrow{V_0} = 
\frac{1}{1+i\omega RC} \overrightarrow{V_0} =  H(\omega) \overrightarrow{V_0}$$

To get the time domain signal you need to turn the complex transfer function, $H$,  into amplitude and phase and you will get something like

$$V_{out}(t) = |H|cos(\omega t + \phi_H)$$

Comment: The OP looks like a homework-like question.  I think you should modify this so that it's not a complete answer, or delete it.